# Why doesn't the replayer work on Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, pgn-viewer

I get that in general we don't want to be asking chess related questions here, but occasionally a meta question or answer can be illuminated with an example where the replayer or just a diagram displayer would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because we (the ♦ moderator team) haven't asked for it yet. I was planning to do so, but then 'other things' happened and I decided not to bother the Community Managers right now.

It would be especially useful for a Sandbox question where users can test the syntax, or to provide a network-intern replayer for chess questions on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Well, it does now. :D Thanks to a note from Glorfindel, you'll find that the replayer has now been activated on Chess Meta so, enjoy!

Thanks to Yaakov for actually making the necessary changes for this!