# Replayer Sandbox

Tags: discussion, support, pgn-viewer

On the main site, we have a feature called the 'PGN viewer' or 'replayer'. How it works is described in this FAQ: [How do I add a replayer to my post?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/7297) and the [pgn-viewer](/questions/tagged/pgn-viewer) tag contains many other questions documenting the various capabilities of the replayer. What we lacked was a space to experiment with it, since the replayer was only active on the main site. Now that the company [kindly activated the replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/902/7297) for us on this Meta as well, this Q&A can be used as a sandbox, not unlike the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

This is a *sandbox*, so it's freely editable by anyone (with [100 reputation](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) or more, since it's a Community Wiki). If you have less reputation, don't worry; you can still post your own answer. The Sandbox can also be used as some kind of reference for other sites in the network (e.g. [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)) when they need to demonstrate a chess game. This usually happens nowadays through links to other websites, but this looks like a decent spot as well. It's recommended to *link back* to the Stack Exchange post where you use it, to make sure somebody here doesn't change the game by accident. And as always, posts should [never depend completely on external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/295232), so the position/game itself must be in the original post as well.

Answer (score 2):

For PSE https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/109105/73836

```
[FEN "nnn5/8/8/NNN5/8/8/8/5k1K w - - 0 1"]

1.Ncb7 Ncb6 2.N5d6 N8d7 3.Nd8 Nd5 4.Nac6 Nac7 5.Nc8 Nc5 6.N6a7 N7a6 7.Ndc6 Ndc7 8.Nb6 Nb7 9.Nac8 Nac5 10.Nb8 Nb5 11.Na8 Na5 *
```

Answer (score 1):

Used in an answer to the Puzzling question [Chess Bloodshed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/104210/11110) (find, with the minimum number of moves, a legal game where all pieces are captured except the two kings):

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "G. Ponzetto - 2000"]
[StartPly "33"]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Bd3 Qxa2 4. Bxh7 Qxb1 5. Bxg8 Qxc2 6. Bxf7+ Kxf7 7. Rxa7 Qxc1 8. Rxb7 Rxh2 9. Rxb8 Rxg2 10. Qxc1 Rxg1+ 11. Rxg1 Rxb8 12. Qxc7 Rxb2 13. Qxc8 Rxd2 14. Qxf8+ Kxf8 15. Rxg7 Rxf2 16. Rxe7 Kxe7 17. Kxf2
```

Answer (score 1):

to support an answer to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/106011/70634) question on PSE:

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 e6 2. d5 Be7 3. d6 g5 4. e4 g4 5. c4 g3 6. b4 gxh2 7. g4 f6 8. g5 c6 9. g6 h5 10. Bg5 fxg5 11. b5 h4 12. b6 h3 13. bxa7 b5 14. a4 b4 15. a5 b3 16. a6 b2 17. Ra5 g4 18. Rc5 Qa5+ 19. Nc3 b1=B 20. dxe7 d5 21. f4 Kd7 22. f5 Ba2 23. f6 Kd6 24. e8=B Ne7 25. f7 Nd7 26. f8=N Nf6 27. Bf7 Rh5 28. Nd7 Rb8 29. g7 Rb5 30. Nb6 Bb7 31. a8=N Re5 32. Ne2 g3 33. Nf4 g2 34. Nc7 g1=N 35. a7 Nf3+ 36. Kf2 Ne1 37. Rg1 h1=B 38. Qh5 Bf3 39. Rg5 h2 40. g8=B h1=B 41. a8=B Nc2 42. Bg2 Ne3 43. exd5 exd5 44. cxd5 cxd5 45. Rxd5+ Rexd5 46. Rxd5+ Bfxd5 47. Bgxd5 Bbxd5 48. Baxd5 Baxd5 49. Bxd5 Bxd5 50. Bxd5 Rxd5 51. N3xd5 N3xd5 52. Nfxd5 Nfxd5 53. Nbxd5 Nxd5 54. Nxd5 Qxd5 55. Qxd5+ Kxd5
```

---

for [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106135/70634) post:

```
[Title "Zdravko Maslar, Problem 1958, Special Prize, h=34"]
[FEN "K1b2rk1/4pr2/1b1n1p2/5q2/3p1p2/1p5n/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
[startflipped ""]


1... f3 2. Kb8 f2 3. Ka8 f1=B 4. Kb8 Bd3 5. Ka8 Bb1 6. Kb8 Ba2 7. Ka8 Qb1 8. Kb8 f5 9. Ka8 f4 10. Kb8 f3 11. Ka8 f2 12. Kb8 f1=B 13. Ka8 Rf2 14. Kb8 Kf7 15. Ka8 Ke6 16. Kb8 Kd5 17. Ka8 Kc4 18. Kb8 Kc3 19. Ka8 Kb2 20. Kb8 Ka1 21. Ka8 Rb2 22. Kb8 Rff2 23. Ka8 Bf5 24. Kb8 Bc2 25. Ka8 d3 26. Kb8 Be3 27. Kc7 e5 28. Kxd6 Bc1 29. Ke6 Rd2 30. Kf5 e4 31. Kg4 Be2+ 32. Kxh3 e3 33. Kg2 Bed1+ 34. Kf1 e2+ 35. Ke1
```

Answer (score 1):

Supporting [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106194/70634) PSE Question.

```
[FEN "7Q/8/3R1R2/K5k1/ppppppp1/N7/1PPPPPPP/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.h4+ gxh3 2.Rg6+ Kf5 3.g4+ fxg3 4.Qf8+ Ke5 5.f4+ exf3 6.Rde6+ Kd5 7.e4+ 
dxe3 8.Qd8+ Kc5 9.d4+ cxd3 10.Qb6+ Kd5 11.c4+ bxc3 12.Qd8+ Kc5 13.b4+ axb3
```

- 

Answer (score 1):

For [this answer on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107611/11110) for a checkmate with only knights:

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 e5 2. dxe5 Nf6 3. exf6 Na6 4. fxg7 Ke7 5. g8=N+ Ke6 6. Nd2 Kd5 7. g4 f6 8. g5 Be7 9. gxf6 Nb8 10. fxe7 Na6 11. exd8=N Nb8 12. Nxb7 Na6 13. b4 Nb8 14. b5 Nc6 15. b6 Nd8 16. bxc7 Rb8 17. cxd8=N Ra8 18. Ngf3 Rb8 19. Nf6#
```

Answer (score 1):

For [@loopywalt's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120365/11110) to the Puzzling.SE question "The Biggest Chess Blunder":

```
[FEN "Rrrqqqqq/PPPPPPP1/kq1qqqbb/7R/K7/4n3/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
[StartPly "1"]
[StartFlipped "0"]

1... Ng4 (1... Bc2#) 2.axb8=Q+ Qa7 3.Rxa7+ Kb6 4.bxc8=Q+ Kc6 5.cxd8=Q+ Qc7 6. Rxc7+ Kd6 7. dxe8=Q+ Qd7+ 8. Rxd7+ Ke6 9. exf8=Q+ Qe7 10.Rxe7+ Kf6 11. fxg8=Q+ Bf7 12. Rxf7+ Kg6 13. Qxg4+ Bg5 14. Rxg5+ Kh6 15.gxh8=Q#
```

Answer (score 0):

A [solution to a puzzle on the main site](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/33306/7297), posted here to avoid spoilers. Stack Exchange spoilers (`>!`) don't support the replayer.

```
[FEN "1q4Nr/4K2k/8/8/8/8/1R6/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. null Kg7 2. null Rh1 3. null Qh2 4. null Qh8 5. null Rh7 6. Rg2#
```

Answer (score 0):

27 consecutive captures on a single square, for a [chess puzzle on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106013/11110):

```
[FEN "7k/2nqnb2/1npqpn2/1QQpqqrr/1NPQPN2/1QNQNB2/3R4/1K1R4 w - - 0 1"]

1. cxd5 cxd5 2. exd5 exd5 3. Nbxd5 Nbxd5 4. Ncxd5 Ncxd5 5. Nexd5 Nexd5 6. Nxd5 Nxd5 7. Bxd5 Bxd5 8. Qb3xd5 Q6xd5 9. Q4xd5 Q5xd5 10. Qcxd5 Qfxd5 11. Qbxd5 Qxd5 12. Qxd5 Rxd5 13. Rxd5 Rxd5 14. Rxd5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for replaying [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/105122/57521).

```
[FEN "p6p/7p/3npp2/2k1q1b1/2P1P1rp/1PP1Pp1r/1NP2PK1/1B1NB1nb w - - 0 1"]

1. Kf1 null 2. Bd2 null 3. Ke1 null 4. Bc1 null 5. Kd2 null 6. Kd3 null 7. Bd2 null 8. Be1 null 9. Kd2 null 10. Kc1 null 11. Ba2 null 12. Kb1 null 13. Ka1 null 14. Bb1 null 15. Ka2 null 16. Ka3 null 17. Ka4 null 18. Ka5 null 19. Ka6 null 20. Ka7 null 21. Kxa8 null 22. Kb8 null 23. Kc7 null 24. Kd7 null 25. Ke7 null 26. Kf8 null 27. Kg8 null 28. Kxh8 null 29. Kxh7 null 30. Kg6 null 31. Kh5 null 32. Kxg4 null 33. Kh5 null 34. Kg6 null 35. Kg7 null 36. Kf8 null 37. Ke7 null 38. Kd7 null 39. Kc7 null 40. Kb8 null 41. Ka7 null 42. Ka6 null 43. Ka5 null 44. Ka4 null 45. Ka3 null 46. Ka2 null 47. Ka1 null 48. Ba2 null 49. Kb1 null 50. Kc1 null 51. Kd2 null 52. Kd3 null 53. Bd2 null 54. Bc1 null 55. Kd2 null 56. Ke1 null 57. Kf1 null 58. Kxg1 null 59. Kf1 null 60. Ke1 null 61. Kd2 null 62. Kd3 null 63. Bd2 null 64. Be1 null 65. Kd2 null 66. Kc1 null 67. Kb1 null 68. Ka1 null 69. Bb1 null 70. Ka2 null 71. Ka3 null 72. Ka4 null 73. Ka5 null 74. Ka6 null 75. Ka7 null 76. Kb8 null 77. Kc7 null 78. Kd7 null 79. Ke7 null 80. Kf8 null 81. Kg7 null 82. Kg6 null 83. Kh5 null 84. Kg4 null 85. Kxh3 null 86. Kg4 null 87. Kh5 null 88. Kg6 null 89. Kg7 null 90. Kf8 null 91. Ke7 null 92. Kd7 null 93. Kc7 null 94. Kb8 null 95. Ka7 null 96. Ka6 null 97. Ka5 null 98. Ka4 null 99. Ka3 null 100. Ka2 null 101. Ka1 null 102. Ba2 null 103. Kb1 null 104. Kc1 null 105. Kd2 null 106. Kd3 null 107. Bd2 null 108. Bc1 null 109. Kd2 null 110. Ke1 null 111. Kf1 null 112. Kg1 null 113. Kxh1 null 114. Kg1 null 115. Kf1 null 116. Ke1 null 117. Kd2 null 118. Kd3 null 119. Bd2 null 120. Be1 null 121. Kd2 null 122. Kc1 null 123. Kb1 null 124. Ka1 null 125. Bb1 null 126. Ka2 null 127. Ka3 null 128. Ka4 null 129. Ka5 null 130. Ka6 null 131. Ka7 null 132. Kb8 null 133. Kc7 null 134. Kd7 null 135. Ke7 null 136. Kf8 null 137. Kg7 null 138. Kg6 null 139. Kh5 null 140. Kg4 null 141. Kxf3 null 142. Kg4 null 143. f4 null 144. fxe5 null 145. exd6 null 146. Kh5 null 147. Kg6 null 148. Kf7 null 149. Ke7 null 150. Kd7 null 151. Kc7 null 152. Kb7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another [PSE chess question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106199/70634):

new new

```
[FEN "4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/4K3 w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.h4 f6 2.g3 h6 3.f4 Kf7 4.Kf2 Kg6 5.Kf3 Kh5 6.Ke4 g5 7.d4 g4 8.Kf5 d5 9.
e4 b5 10.e5 c5 11.e6 a5 12.b4 c4 13.c3 a4 14.a3 *
```

new

```
[FEN "4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/4K3 w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.d4 e5 2.Kd2 Ke7 3.g4 b5 4.g5 b4 5.g6 b3 6.a4 h5 7.Kc3 Kf6 8.Kb4 Kg5 9.
Ka3 Kh6 10.h4 a5 11.c3 f6 12.f4 c5 13.f5 c4 14.e4 d6 15.d5 *
```

orig

```
[FEN "4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/4K3 w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.c4 Kf8 2.c5 Kg8 3.c6 Kh8 4.cxb7 h5 5.f3 c5 6.Kf2 c4 7.Kg3 Kh7 8.Kh4 c3 
9.b8=B cxb2 10.g4 b1=B 11.g5 Bf5 12.Bf4 f6 13.e4 e5 14.exf5 exf4 15.g6+ 
Kh6 16.h3 d5 17.d4 a5 18.a4
```

Answer (score 0):

for PSE [post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106284/70634)

```
[FEN ""]
1.g4 d5 2.g5 d4 3.g6 d3 4.gxh7 dxe2 5.hxg8=N exf1 6.Nf6+ gxf6 >! 7.Ke2 Bg7 8.Ke3 O-O 9.Ne2 Bh8 10.Rxf1 *
```

Answer (score 0):

A replay for [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106285/an-intriguing-game-reconstruction) question.

```
[FEN ""]

1. f4 c6 2. Kf2 Qa5 3. Ke3 Kd8 4. f5 Kc7 5. Qe1 Kb6 6. Qg3 Na6 7. Qb8 h5 8. Nf3 Rh6 9. Ne5 Rg6 10. Qxc8 Rg3+ 11. hxg3 Kb5 12. Rh4 f6 13. Rd4 fxe5 14. b4 exd4+ 15. Kf4 h4 16. Qe8 h3 17. Nc3+ dxc3 18. Ba3 h2 19. Rb1 h1=Q 20. Rb2 cxb2 21. Kg5 Qg1 22. Qh5 Ka4 23. b5 Rc8 24. b6 Rc7 25. bxc7 b1=B 26. c8=R Qc7 27. Bd6 Nb4 28. Kg6 Ka3 29. Ra8 Kb2 30. a4 Qgb6 31. a5 Kc1 32. axb6 Kd1 33. bxc7 Ke1 34. Kf7 Nh6+ 35. Ke8 Ba2 36. f6 Bg8 37. f7 Kxf1 38. c8=B Nd5 39. Bb8 Nc7+ 40. Kd8 Ne8 41. fxe8=R Nf7+ 42. Kc7 Nd8 43. Qf7+ Kg1
```

Answer (score 0):

For [PSE "Black board attack"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106764/70634)

```
[FEN "8/8/8/8/8/8/pppppppp/rnbqkbnr w kq - 0 1"]

1. null Na3 2. null b1=Q 3. null Bb2 4. null c1=Q 5. null Qb3 6. null d1=Q 7. null Qd8 8. null Qh7 9. null Qcc4
```

Answer (score 0):

For [PSE "Black board attack"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106764/70634)

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/8/8 w kq - 0 1"]

1. null d5 2. null d4 3. null d3 4. null d2 5. null d1=Q 6. null Q8d2 7. null e5 8. null Bd7 9. null Bd6 10. null e4
```

Another almost solution:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/8/8 w kq - 0 1"]

1. null h5 2. null h4 3. null h3 4. null h2 5. null h1=Q 6. null Rh3 7. null e5 8. null Qg5 9. null Qd2 10. null b5 11. null d5
```

And another:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/8/8 w kq - 0 1"]

1. null a5 2. null a4 3. null a3 4. null a2 5. null a1=Q 6. null Qb2 7. null Ra1 8. null e5 9. null Qg5 10. null d5 11. null e4
```

Answer (score 0):

For [PSE "Black board attack"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106764/70634)

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/8/8 w kq - 0 1"]

1. null d5 2. null d4 3. null d3 4. null d2 5. null d1=Q 6. null Q8d2 7. null h5 8. null h4 9. null b5 10. null e5
```

Answer (score 0):

For PSE [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106924/70634)

```
[FEN ""]
1.f4 c6 2.Kf2 h5 3.Ke3 Rh6 4.Qe1 Rg6 5.f5 Na6 6.Qg3 f6 7.Qb8 Rg3+ 8.hxg3 Kf7 9.Rh4 Qa5 10.Rd4 h4 11.Nf3 h3 12.Ne5+ fxe5 13.f6 exd4+ 14.Kf4 Ke6 15. b4 Kd5 16.Qxc8 h2 17.Nc3+ dxc3 18.Rb1 h1=Q 19.Rb2 cxb2 20.Qe8 b1=B 21.Ba3 Qg1 22.b5 Kc4 23.Bd6 Rc8 24.Kg5 Rc7 25.Qh5 Qc5+ 26.Kg6 Kb4 27.Kf7 Ka3 28. Ke8 Kb2 29.a4 Ba2 30.b6 Nh6 31.bxc7 Bg8 32.c8=R Qc7 33.a5 Q5b6 34.axb6 Kc1 35.Ra8 Kd1 36.bxc7 Ke1 37.c8=B Kxf1 38.Kd8 Kg1 39.Bb8 Nc7 40.f7 Ne8 41. fxe8=R Nf7+ 42.Kc7 Nd8 43.Qf7 *
```

Answer (score 0):

For my answer to [this question.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107180/piercing-bullets)

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "58"]

1. d4 h6 2. Bg5 hxg5 3. a4 a5 4. Na3 Rh6 5. b4 e5 6. h4 d5 7. g4 Bf5 8. gxf5 Re6 9. fxe6 Ke7 10. Qd2 Kf6 11. hxg5+ Kf5 12. e4+ Kg4 13. Nh3 f5 14. Nf4 Nf6 15. gxf6 Bc5 16. bxc5 Qd6 17. cxd6 c5 18. Rb1 Nc6 19. Nc4 b5 20. Rh3 Rb8 21. Re3 g5 22. Bd3 bxc4 23. Rb4 cxd3 24. c4 Rb5 25. axb5 axb4 26. bxc6 gxf4 27. Qc2 fxe3 28. f4 Kf3 29. Qc3 bxc3
```

Answer (score 0):

Made for [this Puzzling answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107206/1649) on retrograde analysis.

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. h3 h5 2. d3 Nf6 3. Bf4 Na6 4. Bh2 Rh6 5. g3 Ng4 6. Bg2 Rd6 7. Be4 Rd5 8. Nf3 Nb4 9. Rf1 Rb5 10. Bg1 Rc5 11. Qd2 Nh2 12. g4 Rb5 13. Nd4 Rc5 14. Nf5 Rb5 15. Ng3 Rc5 16. Nh1 Rb5 17. Qe3 Rc5 18. Qg3 h4 19. Bg6 hxg3 20. h4 Rb5 21. h5 Rc5 22. h6 Rd5 23. Bh5 Rb5 24. Nc3 Rc5 25. Nb5 Rf5 26. Nc3 Re5 27. Na4 Rf5 28. Nb6 Re5 29. Nxc8 Rf5 30. Nb6 Rc5 31. Nd5 Rb5 32. Nf4 Rc5 33. Ng6 Rd5 34. Nh8 g6 35. a3 Bg7 36. h7 Be5 37. axb4 Kf8 38. c3 Kg7 39. c4 Kh6 40. cxd5 Qg8 41. e3 Qg7 42. d4 Qf6 43. dxe5 Rg8 44. exf6 Rg7 45. fxg7 Kg5 46. g8=N Kh4 47. Nf6 Kg5 48. Ne4+ Kh6 49. Nc3 Kg5 50. Na2 Kf6 51. Nc1 Ke5 52. Na2 Ke4 53. Nc3+ Kd3 54. Na2 Kc4 55. Nc1 Kb5 56. Na2 Ka6 57. Nc1+ Kb6 58. Na2 Kb5 59. Nc1 Kc4 60. Na2 Kd3 61. Nc1+ Ke4 62. Ne2 Ke5 63. Nd4 Kf6 64. Nf3 Kg7 65. Ng5 Kf8 66. Ne4 Ke8 67. Nf6+ Kd8 68. Ng8 Kc8 69. Nf6 Kb8 70. Ng8 Ka8 71. O-O-O
```

Answer (score 0):

For [this Puzzling answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107796/1649) on most pieces involved in a checkmate.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e3 d5 2. Bc4 f5 3. Bxd5 f4 4. Bf7+ Kd7 5. Be8+ Kd6 6. h4 c6 7. Rh3 Kc7 8. Rg3
a6 9. Rg5 Kb6 10. Rd5 Ka7 11. a4 Qd7 12. Ra3 Qf5 13. Rd8 Be6 14. Rc8 Nd7 15. Rd3
Bf7 16. Rd5 Bg6 17. Re5 e6 18. Nc3 Bd6 19. Ne4 Bb8 20. Nd6 Nc5 21. b4 Ne4 22. a5
Nc3 23. h5 Nd5 24. Qg4 Nc7 25. Ke2 Ne7 26. Nh3 Rf8 27. Ng5 Rf6 28. Ngf7 f3+ 29.
Kd1 Ng8 30. Nd8 Bf7 31. c4 Qg5 32. Kc2 Rf4 33. Kc3 Qf5 34. Qg5 Bg6 35. Bb2 Bf7
36. Kb3 Bg6 37. Re4 Bf7 38. Bd4+ Qc5 39. Bc3 Qf5 40. Qe7 g5 41. Bf6 Nh6 42. Qf8
Ng8 43. Qg7 Ne7 44. Qg8 Bg6 45. N8f7 Nb5 46. Re5 Nc7 47. Kc3 Nb5+ 48. Kb3 Nc7
49. e4 Nb5 50. g4 Nc7 51. Kc3 Nb5+ 52. Kd3 Nc7 53. Kd4 Nb5+ 54. Kc5 Nc7 55. d3
Nb5 56. d4 Nc7 57. d5 b5 *
```

Answer (score 0):

Proof game for https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107858/73836

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.Nf3 Nf6 2.Nc3 g6 3.Nh4 Bg7 4.Nf5 O-O 5.g4 Bh8 6.Rg1 a5 7.Nh6+ Kg7 8.Ng8 Ra6 9.g5 Rb6 10.Rg4 Rb4 11.Nb5 Ra4 12.b3 c5 13.Ba3 c4 14.Bb4 c3 15.Rc4 Nc6 16.Bh3 Qb6 17.Kf1 Qe3 18.Kg2 e5 19.f3 e4 20.Kg3 Ng4 21.Qf1 Qd3 22.Kf4 Re8 23.Qg2 Re6 24.Rh1 Rd6 25.Qf1 Nf2 26.Qd1 Nd4 27.Ke5 Qe3 28.Be6 Nf5 29.Na7 Rd3 30.Nb5 Nd4 31.Re1 Nh3 32.a3 Nf2 33.Rf1 Nh3 34.Rh1 Nf2 35.h3 f5 36.gxf6# *
```

Answer (score 0):

For https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107945/73836

```
[FEN "1q1N3k/2prN1R1/Kn3Qn1/1p4p1/1r4b1/1p4b1/2pppp2/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Rxg6+ Kh7 2.Rg7+ Kh8 3.Rxg5+ Kh7 4.Rg7+ Kh8 5.Rxg4+ Kh7 6.Rg7+ Kh8 7.Rxg3+ Kh7 8.Qf7+ Kh8 9.Qf8+ Kh7 10.Rg7+ Kh6 11.Qf6+ Kh5 12.Qg6+ Kh4 13.Qg5+ Kh3 14.Qh5+ Rh4 15.Qf3+ Kh2 16.Qxf2+ Kh3 17.Qf3+ Kh2 18.Rg2+ Kh1 19.Rxe2+ Kg1 20.Rg2+ Kh1 21.Rxd2+ Kg1 22.Rg2+ Kh1 23.Rxc2+ Kg1 24.Qf2+ Kh1 25.Qxh4+ Kg1 26.Qg3+ Kh1 27.Qh3+ Kg1 28.Rg2+ Kf1 29.Qf3+ Ke1 30.Qf2+ Kd1 31.Qe2+ Kc1 32.Qe1+ Rd1 33.Qc3+ Kb1 34.Qxb3+ Ka1 35.Qc3+ Kb1 36.Rb2+ Ka1 37.Rxb5+ Ka2 38.Rb2+ Ka1 39.Rxb6+ ( 39.Rd2+ Kb1 40.Rxd1+ Ka2 41.Rd2+ Kb1 42.Rb2+ Ka1 43.Rxb6+ Ka2 44.Qc2+ Ka1 45.Qd1+ Ka2 46.Rxb8 Ka3 47.Qc1+ Ka2 48.Qxc7 Ka3 49.Qa5# ) 39...Ka2 40.Qb3+ Ka1 41.Qxd1+ Ka2 42.Rxb8 Ka3 43.Qc1+ Ka4 44.Qxc7 Ka3 45.Qa5# *
```

Answer (score 0):

Proof game for [PSE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120593/73836)

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]    

1. h4 a5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nd4 Nd5 4. Nb3 Nc3 5. a3 Nxd1 6. Ra2 Ne3 7. Rh3 Nf5 8. Re3 a4 9. Re6 Ng3 10. Rb6 Nh1 11. Re6 axb3 12. Rd6 bxa2 13. Re6 axb1=B 14. Rd6 Ba2 15. Rc6 Bd5 16. Rd6 Be4 17. Rf6 Bg6 18. Re6 fxe6 19. h5 Bf7 20. h6 g6 21. Kd1 Bg7 22. Ke1 Be5 23. Kd1 Bh2 24. g3 Bg1 25. Bg2 Rf8 26. Bd5 Bg8 27. Ba2 Kf7 28. b3 Kf6 29. Bb2+ Kg5 30. Bd4 Ra5 31. Ba7 b6 32. Ke1 Rff5 33. Kf1 Kh5 34. Kg2 Qf8 35. Kh3 Qg7 36. hxg7 Bf7 37. g8=Q Rg5 38. Qh8 Raf5 39. Qd4 Bb7 40. Qe4 Bd5 41. Qg2 Bf3 42. Qh2 Bg4+ 43. Kg2+ Bh3+ 44. Qxh3#
```